# spring-boot web app's ContextClosedEvent does not complete when app is deployed on cloudfoundry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

```
@Service
public class ShutdownListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ShutdownListener.class);      
    @EventListener(ContextClosedEvent.class)
    public void onContextClosed(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("OAE: event :" + event);
        ApplicationContext ctx = event.getApplicationContext();
        LOGGER.info("OAE: context :" + ctx);
        try {
            LOGGER.info("sleeping");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
            LOGGER.info("slept");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
   }
```

This works fine when spring-boot app is run locally.

When the aapp is deployed to pivotal cloud-foundry with the latest (java-buildpack-v3.5.1.zip) java buildpack as a jar and cf cli is used to stop the app, it indicates that the onContextClosed method is fired, it does not wait for it to complete successfully.

Any suggestions, ideas what's going on here?

Comment: I would guess that there's a time period in which the app is expected to stop. If it doesn't stop within that time, things are cleaned up more forcefully

Comment: I would say so as well

Answer (score 2):

Reference to codebase indicating the timeout  after which SIGKILL is sent to JVM https://github.com/cloudfoundry/warden/blob/master/warden-protocol/lib/warden/protocol/pb/stop.proto#L9-L17

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a special case of the case explained before. Although the hook starts execution, it is possible to be terminated before it completes, in cases such as operating system shutdowns. In this type of cases, the O/S waits for a process to terminate for a specified amount of time once the SIGTERM is given. If the process does not terminate within this time limit, then the O/S terminates the process forcibly by issuing a SIGTERM (or the counterparts in Windows). So it is possible that this happens when the shutdown hook is half-way through its execution.

Comment: Have you found a way to complete the context event?